# change to loop WordPress theme options page

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

i use code to make a WordPress theme options page and
i need help to transform this code to php loop

> > > change $photo_1 and photo_1 auto to $photo_2 etc ---- for x=number

```
<?php
        
        
// in main file
function my_awesome_page_display() {
    

    if (isset($_POST['photo_1'])) {
        $photo_1 = $_POST['photo_1'];
        update_option('photo_1', $photo_1); 
    }
    if (isset($_POST['link_1'])) {
        $link_1 = $_POST['link_1'];
    update_option('link_1', $link_1);    
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST['photo_2'])) {
        $photo_2 = $_POST['photo_2'];
        update_option('photo_2', $photo_2); 
    }
    if (isset($_POST['link_2'])) {
        $link_2 = $_POST['link_2'];
    update_option('link_2', $link_2);    
    }

 if (isset($_POST['photo_2'])) {
        $photo_3 = $_POST['photo_3'];
        update_option('photo_3', $photo_3); 
    }
    if (isset($_POST['link_3'])) {
        $link_3 = $_POST['link_3'];
    update_option('link_3', $link_3);    
    }
    
    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is vague. If you could give more detail as to the use case this would help me in my answer.

I would look into a multi-part form data on the HTML side of things to send a post variable as array.

But if a loop is what you are looking for here what will help.

```
function my_awesome_page_display() {

$counter = 1;

$photo = array();

$link = array();

do{
    
    if (isset($_POST['photo_'.$counter])) {
        
        $photo[$counter] = $_POST['photo_'.$counter];
        
        update_option('photo_'.$counter, $photo_1); 
        
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST['link_'.$counter])) {
        
        $link[$counter] = $_POST['link_'.$counter];
        
        update_option('link_'.$counter, $link_1);
        
    }
    
    
    //Increment the counter by one each time
    
    $counter++;
    
}
while(isset($_POST['photo_'.$counter]));
//Will go until the POST is not set

}
```

I strongly advise you'd use multi-part form data:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    One Photo Input: <input type="text" name="photos[]"/>
    Another Photo Input: <input type="text" name="photos[]"/>
<!-- same for links -->
</form>
```

Then the function to update options could be as simple as follows:

```
function my_awesome_page_display() {

$photos = $_POST['photos'];
$links = $_POST['link'];
    
//Store photos to ONE option called photo

update_option('photos',json_encode($photos));
update_option('links',json_encode($links));
//Use json_decode to get all the values back out of storage



}
```

Comment: thank you @evolove  | the loop is  help 
but in the loop how i can make the    $photo_1 variable in  
  $photo_1 = $_POST['photo_'.$counter];
change to $photo_2 , $photo_3 , etc depend on $counter

Comment: Sorry. I have edited my Code to reflect this. You should use an array to store with a key=>value relationship

Comment: Another method you can use, again, not recommended would be to use a variable in the variable declarations like this:  $photo_{$counter} = 'valuehere'; then later on you can call $photo_1 or $photo_2 etc.